# flutter throws gradle error after gradle cache

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I cached gradle in my linux machine and set it to path,
when i created a new app it run successfully offline but after adding some dependencies gradle keeps downloading artifacts then fails at the end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, post the error as well so other users know what exactly you're dealing with and can help accordingly.